# parseDateTime output difference

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2018

My Coldfusion Development Server:

```
Server Product  ColdFusion
Version     11,0,13,303668 
Tomcat Version  7.0.75.0
Edition     Developer  
Operating System    Windows 10
```

Coldfusion Production Server:

```
Server Product  ColdFusion 2018
Version 2018.0.04.314546
Tomcat Version  9.0.10.0
Edition Standard  
Operating System    Windows Server 2016
```

```
<cfscript>
    t = parseDateTime("2019-11-10 23:20:51.000","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    writeDump(t);
</cfscript>
```

Running the same code above the output are not the same.

Development Server Output:

```
{ts '2019-11-10 23:20:51'} - Good
```

Production Server Output:

```
{ts '2020-08-10 23:00:51'} - Bad
```

What settings do I need to adjust to make both output similar? What am I missing?

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion

Comment: I've put on labels for the CF versions.

Comment: Vlad, I would strongly suggest that if your Production server is CF 2018, you should upgrade your Dev server to 2018 also. You will be doing yourself a great disservice by developing on CF11 for CF2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Vlad Yes. I go through your issues in my local. I can able to reproduce that issue. But the thing is the pop-conversion argument **mm is deprecated. Use nn for minutes.**

**ColdFusion (2016 release) Update 3:**

```
-- You can use the masks t and tt to create a date/time object. For single-character time marker string, use t. For multiple-character time marker string, use tt.
-- mm is deprecated. Use nn for minutes.
```

So your code should be like,

```
<cfscript>
        t = parseDateTime("2019-11-10 23:20:51.000","yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss");
        writeDump(t);
</cfscript>
```

**Output :**
**{ts '2019-11-10 23:20:51'}**

Now your output same as older version of CF. Please check it and confirm that.

For your more reference please visit https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsedatetime.html

Comment: nn works but errors in my local dev. I've missed that nn I didn't notice it at first.

Comment: Vlad. As I mentioned please check your update details. That should work from cf2016 update 3.